# access array of this kind?

Tags: php, arrays

How to access this kind of array? I want to check email and password for login?
 This is a simple login page. 
The user will enter email and password. 
I am fetching data from third party application i.e infusionSoft. 
So for that i need to fetch all the data first and then check for correct login and password. 
but i am not able to access the data i got. This is dummy data.

```
 array(4) {
    [0]=>
        array(4) {
             ["Email"]=>
             string(26) "samruddhi18dsw10@gmail.com"
             ["Id"]=>
             int(661937)
           }
    [1]=>
         array(4) {
                  ["Phone1"]=>
                  string(14) "(704) 565-5781"
                  ["Email"]=>
                  string(26) "samruddhi18rer10@gmail.com"
          }
     }
```

The data is stored in this variable and

```
     $returnFields = array('Id','FirstName','Email','Phone1','_PasswordStf'); 

     $contacts = $app->dsFind('Contact',999,0,'Groups',8749,$returnFields);

     echo '<pre>';var_dump($contacts);echo '<pre>';
```

I just want to use this condition for login

```
    if ($array_name['email'] == "$user_name" && $array_name['password'] == "$password")
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, "_Example #6 Accessing array elements_"

Comment: Explain more about your wish. I think you wan't to check existence of email in arrays.

Comment: i am getting data in this array and from this array i want to check mail id and password. This is dummy data. actual data consists of email,id, password etc

Comment: explain more detail please

Answer (score 2):

The root array is an **indexed array**, so you have to use indexes to access it's elements, while the child arrays are **associative**, you have to use their keys to access them.

so, to check email and password (for example), you could write the following:

```
<?php

$email = $your_array[0]["Email"];
$password = $your_array[0]["Password"];
```

Where `$your_array` is the name of your root array, `[0]` is the index of the child array that you want to access, and `["Email"]` is the key of the child array element.

**Updated**

I think you are trying to do the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($contacts); $i++)
{
    $given_email = null;
    $given_password = null;

    if(is_array($contacts[$i])){

        if(!empty($contacts[$i]["Email"])){

            $given_email = $contacts[$i]["Email"];
        }

        if(!empty($contacts[$i]["Password"])){

            $given_password = $contacts[$i]["Password"];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($given_email) && $given_email == $user_name && !empty($given_password) && $given_password == $password){

        // login success
    }
}
```

[check the PHP manual for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: so what if i want to access $email = $your_array[1]["Email"];

Comment: i mean i just cant go and check array with its indexes individually @mohammad

Comment: @aakankshakhandelwal loop over the root array, by using `for($i=0; $i < sizeof($your_array); $i++)` as an example

Comment: i have tried doing this but then i am not able to access dont know why

Comment: @aakankshakhandelwal you have to be more specific about what are you trying to reach, and share us what you have tried to do

Comment: for($i=0; $i < sizeof($contacts); $i++)
         {
             echo '<pre>';var_dump($contacts[$i]);echo '<pre>';
         }

Comment: its a simple login page ! user will input data i.e email and password. Our data is stored in third party application named infusion soft ! I am just fetching data from that application. and checking email and password

Comment: @aakankshakhandelwal please update your question and share what have you tried

Comment: so this is what i am getting in  $given_email = $contacts[$i]["Email"];............. variable samruddhi18dsw10@gmail.comsamruddhi18rer10@gmail.comaakan@gyadmin4444@arfeenkhan.com .....all the email ids :D

Comment: @aakankshakhandelwal how you have different emails, and you are using it for login, how could you know the correct email address? there should a specific one for sure, in a specific position in the array !!

Comment: actually the scene is...As i am third party Application to do login...it doesnt work like mysql where in you put query. In this I will have to Take all the data and from that data i will have to check whether the login credentials are correct or not

Comment: @aakankshakhandelwal you should have one valid position for the email address or the username that is being used to login, you can't "Take all the data and from that data i will have to check whether the login credentials are correct or not", unless it's a multi-check credentials for multiple users !!!

Comment: yes thats what! but i have no other option. from the above array i will have to check because i cant use any query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix between an indexed array and a associative array. So you can do a check to make sure the data is there before you proceed, if that is what you are looking for?

For example:

```
if(isset($user[1]["email"]) && !empty($user[1]["email"]))
{

   echo "User email: " . $user[1]["email"];
}
```